# How to import a partitioned table into a table with a different number of partitions? (Oracle 10g)

Tags: oracle, import, oracle10g, export, partitioning

I have an existing database with tables which each have 4 partitions (there are tables using both RANGE and HASH partitioning).

I need to import it into another database with a pre-created schema where the same tables will have 8 partitions.

How do I do this? Does this "just work" if I do a table-level import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Use the `IGNORE=Y` setting and have the table precreated in the target schema/database the way you want it physically organized.  The main problem you can run into is if you don't have the same "coverage" in the target system -- if there aren't partitions/subpartitions that can hold all the data you're importing from the source.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the partition values are the same. If 4 of the partitions in the new table have the same partition values as the old table, then you can import into a table set up the same as the old table, then split the partitions as necessary to get your 8 new partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too much concerned about performance, just treat the process as moving data from one table to another. The platform will take of the rest.

Comment: that's the "it just works" outcome? A table-level  import will just sort things out? Good news, if so (as we're not that bothered about performance, the db is not huge right now and it's a one-off migration)

Comment: I have had success with a INSERT INTO new_table SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM old_table, where the partitions on old_table and new_table were not the same, so yes. Unless there are specific constraints to factor in, it may well work.